# ListBox.SelectionChanged when Clicking on an userControl inside listboxItem

Tags: wpf, user-controls, listbox

I have `ListBox` and a UserControl inside the `ListBoxItem`.
When I am clicking on the user control the  `ListBox.SelectionChanged` does not fired (I want it to be fired) I do I do that?

Xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="List" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         Foreground="Transparent" 
         BorderBrush="Transparent" 
         Background="Transparent" 
         SelectionMode="Multiple" Grid.Row="2"                       
         SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:Message HorizontalAlignment="Left" .../>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a control in your DataTemplate that handles mouse clicks (e.g. a TextBox that gets the keyboard focus), this will prevent the ListBox from receiving these events.

You could simply disable mouse event handling in your control by setting [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) to false:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <my:Message IsHitTestVisible="False" .../>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```